# Факториал больших чисел

Tags: c, функции, рекурсия, вывод, факториал

Нужно посчитать факториал числа N, где 1<=N<=1000. Также нужно обеспечить до 3000 символов в ответе. Я написала программу и в компиляторе она работает прекрасно:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

static void
factorial (long n, mpz_t r)
{ 
  mpz_init_set_si (r, 1);
  for (; n > 1; n--) {
    mpz_mul_si (r, r, n);
  }
}

int
main (void)
{
  int n;
  mpz_t r;
  while (scanf ("%d", &n) == 1) {
    factorial (n, r);
    gmp_printf ("%Zd\n", r);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Но система тестирования не принимает код, т.к. не знает библиотеки GMP. Подскажите, как это обойти?

Comment: Не использовать эту библиотеку

Comment: Написать СВОЙ код... Цель-то именно в этом, а не научить вас использовать готовую библиотеку.

Comment: Но так же код получается гораздо проще и лаконичнее :)

Comment: "Лучше, конечно, помучиться" (с) Товарищ Сухов

Comment: есть еще один вариант, сейчас домучаю его и добавлю

Comment: Посмотрите тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1153271/195342 - может, на что натолкнет. Поищите по сайту длинную арифметику, большие числа... Если б у вас был С++, а не С - то тут практически готовый код: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1151180/195342

Comment: другой вариант домучен, но все равно система тестирования не желает его принимать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Короче говоря, вот такой код  в итоге приняла система:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
#define MAX 3000

int multiply(int x, int res[], int res_size);
 
void factorial(int n)
{
    int res[MAX];
     
    res[0] = 1;
    int res_size = 1;
     
    for (int x=2; x<=n; x++)
        res_size = multiply(x, res, res_size);
 
    for (int i=res_size-1; i>=0; i--)
        printf ("%d",res[i]);
}
 
int multiply(int x, int res[], int res_size)
{
    int carry = 0;  // Инициализируем перенос
     
    for (int i=0; i<res_size; i++)
    {
        int prod = res[i] * x + carry;
         
        res[i] = prod % 10;  
         
        carry  = prod/10;    
    }
    
    while (carry)
    {
        res[res_size] = carry%10;
        carry = carry/10;
        res_size++;
    }
    return res_size;
}
 
int main()
{   int n;
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    factorial(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего система тестирования от вас требует знания того, как работает длинная арифметика, а также умения записать это в коде (то есть достаточного владения языком программирования). Вряд-ли целью системы является проверка лаконичности или простоты вашего кода.

Но если вам уж совсем не хочется реализовывать вручную длинную арифметику, то я вижу ещё один выход: взять код библиотеки и скопипастить его себе в файл. С этим могут возникнуть проблемы:

- у системы скорее всего есть лимит на размер решения, а вы можете так его превысить;
- если ваше решение также будет проверять человек (например, если вы выполняете задание как ученик, то иногда учителя так делают), то вашу уловку раскроют;

По сути такой трюк практически равносилен списыванию в случае, если вашим заданием было написать код именно на С. Если же из вариантов также доступны Java или Python (которые поддерживают длинные числа на уровне стандартной библиотеки), то это скорее  выравнивание шансов :)

PS: [вот вариант библиотеки](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-bignum-c), которую можно было бы встроить себе в решение: . В тестах даже есть [пример вычисления факториала](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-bignum-c/blob/master/tests/factorial.c) с её использованием.

Comment: Фу, неспортивно... :)

Comment: @Harry полностью согласен :) Но вопрос был в том, как обойти это ограничение тестирующей системы; другой вопрос - как автор использует эти знания)

Answer (score 0):

Вот другое решение, но система тестирования опять-таки не хочет его принимать...

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i,j,d,sz,n=30;
    char *f=calloc(2,sizeof(char));
    *f='1';
    for(d=0,i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        sz=strlen(f);
        for(j=sz-1; j>=0; j--,d/=10)
        {
            d+=(f[j]-'0')*i;
            f[j]=d%10+'0';
        }
        for(sz++; d; d/=10,sz++)
        {
            f=realloc(f,(sz+1)*sizeof(char));
            memmove(f+1,f,sz*sizeof(char));
            *f=d%10+'0';
        }
        //printf("%s\n",f);
    }
    printf("%d!=%s\n",n,f);
    free(f);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваша программа совершенно верно вычислила 1000!, так что ищите проблемы, скорее всего, в выводе - в том ли формате, нужно ли писать перед выводом само число, как считывать n и так далее...

Comment: Система выводит Security Violation, а почему - не знаю...

Comment: Попробуйте убрать строку `system("pause");`.

Comment: тогда ответ будет неверный

Comment: Почему?! проверяющая система вообще не должна ничего ждать, а тут еще и запуск внешнего приложения...

Comment: @A_Hatake это скорее всего говорит о том, что вызов к `system` как к запрещённой функции просто маскирует неправильный ответ. Этот вызов во всяком случае нужно выкинуть, он просто заменяет одну ошибку другой, но не делает решение правильнее

Comment: в любом случае, я написала другую программу, которую в итоге приняли :)

Comment: Кстати, а в каком именно виде вы скидывали это решение? Это же не может быть этот код, поскольку этот даже не читает `n`, ещё и лишний вывод делает

Comment: тут просто основная мысль показана, а отправляла я немного другой